# How to pack a 64bit integer with PHP32?

Tags: php, 64-bit, pack

I want to use `$_REQUEST` to get a 64-bit integer, but it does not support 64-bit. (It will be turned to a float.) I need to pack this data and send to service. However it should be big endian byte order, so I can't use format `f` (float (machine dependent size and representation)) to pack it.

I tried to break it to four 16-bit integers, but I can't use `<<`,`>>`or `&` because it's a float.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`gmp_div_qr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-div-qr.php) with 256 or 65536 multiple times to break it up into 8- or 16-bit chunks, then convert those chunks into strings.